# repainting my panel with objects

Tags: java, swing, repaint

I created a program that is supposed to draw a circle with each click(Random size and random color), and each circle is going to be an object. I don't know what is going on but my code doesn't work and I am pretty sure I am almost there.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class Circle
{

    private JFrame frame;
    CircleObj circleObj;
    Random  rand;
    int rColor;
    int gColor;
    int bColor;
    int radius;



    public static void main (String [] arg)
        {

        frame = new JFrame("Circles");
        frame.setBounds(200, 100, 600, 480);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel top = new JPanel();
        rand = new Random();

        top.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
        {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
                {
                int xstart = e.getX();
                int ystart = e.getY();
                rColor = rand.nextInt(256);
                gColor = rand.nextInt(256);
                bColor = rand.nextInt(256);
                radius = rand.nextInt(20);
                circleObj = new CircleObj(xstart, ystart, rColor, gColor, bColor, radius);

                repaint();

                }
        });
                frame.add(top, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                frame.setVisible(true);

        }


}
```

and here is my CircleObj class

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class CircleObj extends JPanel

{
    private int xVal;
    private int yVal;
    private int red;
    private int green;
    private int blue;
    private int circleRadius;


    public CircleObj (int x, int y, int r, int g, int b, int rad)
        {
        xVal = x;
        yVal = y;
        red = r;
        green= g;
        blue = b;
        circleRadius = rad;

        }



        public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(new Color(red, green, blue));
        g.fillOval(xVal,yVal,circleRadius,circleRadius);
        }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You add a MouseListener to the top JPanel, but when do you add the top JPanel to the top-level window, the GUI? ---  In the **MouseListener**! So this will never work since the top JPanel is not part of the GUI initially, and only gets added when a MouseListener that is added to it is triggered. The MouseListener only works on components that are visible and on the GUI.

Next you create a CircleObj object, but never draw with it in any JComponent's or JPanel's paiintComponent method.

> I am pretty sure I am almost there.

So no, not quite. You will want to re-start and:

- Create a JPanel that has a decent paintComopnent method override,
- Add this JPanel to the JFrame to the GUI **from the beginning**.
- Add an `ArrayList<CircleObj>` to this drawing JPanel
- Change your CircleObj class so that it doesn't extend JPanel, but does have a `public void draw(Grpahics g)` method that will draw it.
- Add a MouseListener to the JPanel that controls this drawing. In your MouseListener, add a new CircleObj to the ArrayList and call `repaint()` to get the drawing JPanel to draw.
- In the JPanel's paintComponent override, iterate through the `ArrayList<CircleObj>` calling each object's `draw(g)` method.
- Read the [Swing graphics tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html).

Comment: @iali87 As this answer shows, there is a lot to do. I suggest breaking this down into small pieces. For example, you might want to start with drawing **one** circle on a JPanel. The location and size of the circle should be hardcoded to start with, just to keep things easy. In fact, draw a circle **without** the `CircleObj` class and then add it in later. From there add something a little more complex. Keep adding a little at a time until you finish the project.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels First thank you... I created the code accordingt to your advice...I am only not sure how to store each click's paint into an ArrayList of objects.

Comment: @iali87: you need to do it in the MouseListener. You could even give the drawing JPanel a method -- `addCircle(Point p)` and in it, let the drawing panel create a new Circle from the mouse point, and then just call this method from within the MouseListener. Keep at it, and you'll get it, but never guess and throw code up willy nilly without first thinking through the logic, else you'll end up with code like what you've posted above.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels
I answered my question( according to your advice) Do you think it is correct ?

Comment: @iali87: You can answer easily if it is correct or not: does it behave correctly? Does it add objects that are drawn using a MouseListener? Your MouseListener does not do this I'm afraid, and you have no separate Circle objects that get added to the drawing JPanel.

Comment: @iali87: so to answer your "second approach" -- I wouldn't do it that way, I'd do it the way outlined in my answer above.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a second approach... How would I be able to tweak it store each circle in an object (Arraylist of objects) ?

```
public class Circle {
        public static void main (String[] arg) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Circles");
        CircleObj canvas = new CircleObj();

        frame.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setBounds(250, 98, 600, 480);
        //frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        } // end main
    } //end Circle
```

CircleObj Class

```
public class CircleObj extends JPanel {
    private int rColor;
    private int gColor;
    private int bColor;
    private int radius;
    private Random rand = new Random();
    private int xStart;
    private int yStart;

    public CircleObj () {
    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent e) {

        xStart = e.getX();
        yStart = e.getY();
        rColor = rand.nextInt(256);
        gColor = rand.nextInt(256);
        bColor = rand.nextInt(256);
        radius = rand.nextInt(20);
        System.out.println("xstart : " + xStart + ", ystart : " + yStart + ", rColor : " + rColor + ", gColor = " +
                gColor + ", bColor: " + bColor + ", radius: " + radius);

        repaint();
        }
    }); // end addMouseListener
    }

    public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(new Color(rColor, gColor, bColor));
    g.fillOval(xStart, yStart, radius, radius);
    }

}
```